# Optimize a joined MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

There is this query that have been bugging me in two days now, it used to work good but now it slows down the entire cluster environment, the query is as seen below:

```
SELECT  userUploads.*,
        users_avatar.avatar AS avatar
FROM    userUploads
        LEFT JOIN users_avatar
            ON userUploads.udid = users_avatar.udid
        INNER JOIN user_subscription
            ON (
                    user_subscription.sub_1 = 'G:123456789'
                    AND user_subscription.sub_2 = userUploads.udid
                )
WHERE   userUploads.platform = 'Private'
        AND userUploads.STATUS IN  ( 'featured', 'approved' )
ORDER   BY userUploads.id DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help out with this query.

Below is the explain of the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys        | key      | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | userUploads       | range  | platform,udid,status | platform | 154     | NULL                   |   12 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users_avatar      | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY  | 182     | Seeds.userUploads.udid |    1 |                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_subscription | ref    | sub_1,sub_2          | sub_1    | 93      | const                  |    7 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT** show create table can seen below

Below is the show create table for the tables hope you have any ideas dancrumb.

```
| users_avatar | CREATE TABLE `users_avatar` (
`udid` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`avatar` varchar(448) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`udid`)
) ENGINE=ndbcluster DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

| userUploads | CREATE TABLE `userUploads` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`bdaha` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`user` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`direktoren` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`filnamnet` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`karhes` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`version` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`rostat` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`stars` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`statyn` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`platform` char(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`images` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`udid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`favorirepris` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`hikes` char(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'no',
`dbn` char(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`timestamp` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`comments` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`klistret` enum('no','yes') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `platform` (`platform`,`status`),
KEY `udid` (`udid`),
KEY `hikes` (`hikes`),
KEY `bdaha` (`bdaha`),
KEY `statyn` (`statyn`),
KEY `version` (`version`)
) ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=118831 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |


| user_subscription | CREATE TABLE `user_subscription` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sub_1` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`sub_2` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `sub_1` (`sub_1`),
KEY `sub_2` (`sub_2`)
) ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=155184 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the three tables involved here, please?

Comment: I can't answer my own question as i am new here :( how can i show you the SHOW CREATE TABLE ? it's to long to paste it here...

Comment: I posted the show create table in the original post :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a filesort on userUploads which is always slow. You may want to play with indices to remove that. For example, you may want to start with an index on udid, platform, and status.

Comment: Filesort is not necessarily slow. It just means that there is a sort that can't use an index: **[What does Using filesort mean in MySQL?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/)**

Comment: how can i optimize the query with that in mind? you have any example?

Comment: First try creating an index on ( id, udid, platform, status ). Also, do you really need to ORDER by id? I assume that is an arbitrary identifier so removing the ORDER BY will also speed things up a little. Then could you paste the new query plan without the ORDER BY and the new index?

Comment: in which table should i create those index as i have udid and platform as index in the userUploads table, I dont want to index status as 95% of all the rows have the same status only a few have status pending, should I index id? i have it as an primary key and auto increment should i index it even though it's an PK? And to asnwer your question yeah i need to sort them actually as i'm sorting by the newest upload

Comment: There is nothing like trying it. First do an index on userUploads with (id, udid, platform, status) even though status has low selectivity and see what query plan/perf stats it results in. Also, can you have userUploads WITHOUT an avatar? Is that why you are using a LEFT JOIN? I might also play with an index on the other table on sub1 and sub2 in the same index. Again, play around and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

In general when querying you want to perform the most limiting operations in terms of data returned first so that other operations are only performed on the data that is actually in the results.

In this case try reordering the inner join to user_subscription and the left join to users_avatar. This way it will only attempt to even get the avatar for a user if they are actually in the result set rather than it looking up all the avatars first then filtering based on joins and where clauses.

```
SELECT  userUploads.*,
    users_avatar.avatar AS avatar
FROM    userUploads
INNER JOIN user_subscription
            ON (
                    user_subscription.sub_1 = 'G:123456789'
                    AND user_subscription.sub_2 = userUploads.udid
                )
LEFT JOIN users_avatar
            ON userUploads.udid = users_avatar.udid

WHERE   userUploads.platform = 'Private'
        AND userUploads.STATUS IN  ( 'featured', 'approved' )
ORDER   BY userUploads.id DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: how would that query look like?

Comment: i did this without success